# Multiple JOINS do not work in a nested JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

Why am I unable to join multiple tables?

If I were to run this SQL code without the second INNER JOIN, it works just fine.

```
SELECT a.name, c1.text, c2.text
FROM `table_a` a
INNER JOIN (
    `table_b` b
    INNER JOIN `table_c1` c1 ON b.info_id = c1.id
    INNER JOIN `table_c2` c2 ON b.info_id = c2.id
) ON a.id = b.person_id;
```

However, if I add a second JOIN -> `INNER JOIN table_c2 c2 ON b.info = c2.id`, it ceases to work properly, and won't select anything.

Here is a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a256d3/1) for the following problem.

My desired result is that I want it to select from both tables
`table_c1` and `table_c2`.

Here it selects only with `table_c1`.

```
SELECT a.name, c1.text
FROM `table_a` a
INNER JOIN (
    `table_b` b
    INNER JOIN `table_c1` c1 ON b.info_id = c1.id
) ON a.id = b.person_id;
```

[image]
I would want there to be a third row with name "Bob", and text "more_other_table_text"

Comment: Please read[Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question) and update the question. With the given info there isn't much to help only the fact that the condition `ON a.id = b.person_id` should be after  `table_b b`

Comment: Please include a few rows of sample data and the expected result. It's not clear what result you want.

Comment: I'm sorry, one second I will try to format it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things you can do to achieve this:

1. `LEFT JOIN` between `table_b` and `c1 & c2`.
2. `IFNULL` to check for text in `c1`, otherwise return text from `c2`.
3. `GROUP BY` without an aggregate function to remove the duplicate *Sam* values from the result set based on the order they were entered into `table_2` (you did not specify what value you want when the same `person_id` is entered multiple times in `table_2`, if you would like to see both `c1` and `c2` texts with duplicate `names`, remove the `GROUP BY`).

See [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a256d3/106)

```
SELECT a.name, IFNULL(c1.text, c2.text) as `text`
    FROM `table_a` a
    INNER JOIN (
        `table_b` b
        LEFT JOIN `table_c1` c1 ON b.info_id = c1.id
        LEFT JOIN `table_c2` c2 ON b.info_id = c2.id
    ) ON a.id = b.person_id 
     GROUP BY a.name
     ORDER BY a.id ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to put your join condition next to the join:

```
SELECT a.name, b.age, c1.text, c2.text
 FROM table_a a
 INNER JOIN table_b b ON a.id = b.person_id
 INNER JOIN table_c1 c1 ON b.info = c1.id
 INNER JOIN table_c2 c2 ON b.info = c2.id
```

You may also use parentheses, but there is no advantage to doing so:

```
SELECT a.name, b.age, c1.text, c2.text
 FROM table_a a
 INNER JOIN (
    table_b b
    INNER JOIN table_c1 c1 ON b.info = c1.id
    INNER JOIN table_c2 c2 ON b.info = c2.id
 )
 ON a.id = b.person_id
```

Comment: Perhaps I had phrased my question wrong, I am sorry. I have edited it for better understanding.